# What is the probability of three union if one of the events has probability zero?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, statistics, intersection-theory

my problem is this:
We throw $n$ bells randomly into $3$ boxes initially empty. Compute the probability that at least One boxes remaining empty.
I have the solution and that is:
$$
P(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3) = P(A_1) + P(A_2) + P(A_3) - P(A_1 \cap A_2) - P(A_3 \cap A_2) - P(A_1 \cap A_3) + P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3)
$$
$$
P(A_1)=(2/3)^n
$$
$$
P(A_1 \cap A_2) = 1/3^n
$$
$$
P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3) = 0
$$
But question is: why the probability of the intersection of two is not $0$? In other words, why the probability of the intersection of three is $0$ but the intersection of $2$ is not $0$? Aren't they $3$ disjoint events? How is it possible that a ball is in $A_1$ AND $A_2$?

Comment: A ball is not "in" A1 and A2, because A1 and A2 are events, not boxes. Maybe you should write down what A1 and A2 are, and then you can ask yourself what their intersection is.

Comment: So P(A1) is the probability that the first box Is empty?

Comment: It seems to me that $A_i$ is the event that box $i$ remains empty. Can you clarify or  confirm?

Comment: Yes It Is! Thank you now I understand!

Comment: Yes, $\Pr(A_1)$ is the probability that box1 is empty... without commenting on the emptiness or not of the remaining two boxes.  $\Pr(A_1\cap A_2)$ is the probability of both the first and second boxes being empty, which is possible precisely when all of the balls went into box 3.  $\Pr(A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3)$ is the probability that all three boxes are simultaneously empty, but this is clearly going to happen with zero probability so long as $n\geq 1$ since at least one of the boxes can not be empty since it receives at least the first of the balls.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!